# Analytical solution for an almost geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Is there any way of solving explicitly the limit of the series

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n a^{p ^ n}$

where $0<p,q<1$ and $a>0$?

The series is obviously convergent as $a^{p ^ n} < \max(a,1)$ and so you can bound it by a standard geometric series, but it would be helpful to have an exact expression for it as well.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Eep, a nested exponential. I doubt this has a tidy closed form...

Comment: Tidy or not, I'm pretty sure there is no closed form except in the trivial case $a=1$.